# UINavigationController view controller stack order is incorrect when using the "long press back button" feature in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uikit, ios14

I've noticed that, when using the long-press back button feature in iOS 14, any properties relating to `UINavigationController`'s view controller stack (`.viewControllers`, `.topViewController`, etc.) seem incorrect. Specifically, the order is reversed.

Regarding the `.viewControllers` property, Apple's docs state:

> The root view controller is at index 0 in the array, the back view controller is at index n-2, and the top controller is at index n-1, where n is the number of items in the array.

If I've got three view controllers in a nav stack like as follows
`[ViewController01, ViewController02, ViewController03]` and print out the `.viewControllers` property in `viewWillAppear`, I get the expected output of:

```
[ViewController01]
[ViewController01, ViewController02]
[ViewController01, ViewController02, ViewController03]
```

If I tap the back button from `ViewController03`, I get the expected output from `viewWillAppear` in `ViewController02`:

`[ViewController01, ViewController02]`

However, if I set everything up again so I've got `[ViewController01, ViewController02, ViewController03]` and then use the long-press back button feature to jump back to `ViewController01`, I get the **unexpected** output of:

`[ViewController03, ViewController01]`

From `viewWillAppear` in `ViewController01`.

I'm not expecting this because `ViewController03` isn't, and never was, the root view controller of the navigation stack. As per the docs, I'm expecting:

`[ViewController01, ViewController03]`

Could someone please let me know if this is expected behaviour or if I've overlooked something super-obvious?

Thank you!

I've reproduced this in a small sample app based on a "single view controller" project. Just embed the initial view controller in a nav stack and include the following:

```
class StubViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print("\(self) will appear. Current nav stack follows:")
        print("\(self.navigationController?.viewControllers ?? [])")
    }

}

class ViewController: StubViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(TestViewController01(), animated: true)
    }

}

class TestViewController01: StubViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(TestViewController02(), animated: true)
    }

}

class TestViewController02: StubViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(TestViewController03(), animated: true)
    }
}

class TestViewController03: StubViewController {
}
```

(I'm aware the above is very horrible)

Comment: I am having this issue as well, it's annoying, since I am using `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to determine if the __current__ viewcontroller via `navigationController.first` matches the __first__ view controller and not hide the bottom bar. With the array reversed when going back from the long press back button menu, this is no longer dependable.

Comment: Also what I noticed is that in the usual back press, the stack is normal, e.g. `[VC1, VC2, VC3]` . My overridden `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` in my BaseVC is called as I click on Back button in VC3, the printed `self` is `VC2`, and stack is `[VC1, VC2]`, as expected. However, when using the long press to go from `VC3`  to `VC1`, `self` is now `VC1` (as expected), _but_ the stack is `[VC3, VC1]` instead of `[VC1, VC2, VC3]`.

Comment: For posterity sake, I simply workaround this issue by adding a function `shouldHidesBottomBarWhenPushed()` to my base class which is called when `get` in my overridden `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` var, and have the derived classes implement `shouldHidesBottomBarWhenPushed()` when needed to.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what's happening here is that you have accidentally looked inside the sausage factory and you've seen how the sausage is made. And it isn't pretty...!

The workaround is: don't do that. Give the view controllers stack a chance to settle down before you look at it:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("\(self) will appear. Current nav stack follows:")
        print("\(self.navigationController?.viewControllers ?? [])")
    }
}
```

Even more simple: just move the code to `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: Thanks for the response - do you know why this happens or why this wouldn't be documented?

I totally understand what you're saying around "peaking inside the sausage factory", but I thought that would have applied more if I was using private methods or suchlike. 
The docs for `.viewControllers` and pals appear very clear-cut and well-defined, and there's no warning saying that the definition changes during (for example) a pop transition.

Answer (score 0):

i'm stuck with this too, but what i've found is navigation controller changed the viewControllers stack because of animation to handle what controller will goes to another in back operation
for example if stack is [vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4] and you are in vc4 and if you call

```
navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
```

stack will be [vc4, vc1] in willShow delegate method.

the only way i found is to set animation to false

```
navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
```

to keep the stack as what it really is